# Validate JOptionPane text fields

Tags: java, if-statement, joptionpane, messagedialog

Please help me validate (make sure) all four of my JOptionPane text fields are filled with some information before adding information to the tableModel.
If some of the fields are empty, warning dialogue must be shown. And JOptionPane must be reopened for user to complete all of four fields.

```
newUser.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        String[] options = {"Ierakstīt", "Atcelt"};
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\AdrianP\\Desktop\\kursovaja\\User-48.png");
        int n = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(w, myPanel, "Pievienot jaunu lietotāju", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, 0, icon, options, options[1]);

        if (n == 0) {

            if (nameField.getText().equals("")  && lastNameField.getText().equals("") && groupField.getText().equals("") && idField.getText().equals("")) {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(w, "Kļūda!", "Lūdzu, ievadiet datus!", 0, icon);
                nameField.setText(null);
                lastNameField.setText(null);
                idField.setText(null);
                groupField.setText(null);
                JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(w, myPanel, "Pievienot jaunu lietotāju", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, 0, icon, options, options[1]);

            } else {

                tableModel.addRow(new Object[] {nameField.getText(), lastNameField.getText(), idField.getText(), groupField.getText()});
                nameField.setText(null);
                lastNameField.setText(null);
                idField.setText(null);
                groupField.setText(null);

            }

        } else {

            nameField.setText(null);
            lastNameField.setText(null);
            idField.setText(null);
            groupField.setText(null);

        }

    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here in your condition you check all parts as needed:

```
 if (nameField.getText().equals("")  && lastNameField.getText().equals("") && groupField.getText().equals("") && idField.getText().equals(""))
```

When you want to check if any of the TextFields is empty and don't see to other, you can change "&&" to "|" or "||". For example:

```
 if (nameField.getText().equals("")  | lastNameField.getText().equals("") | groupField.getText().equals("") | idField.getText().equals(""))
```

You can use more complex construction to organize your conditions, for example, using JOptionPane:

```
int rc = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "The typeR : is not loaded. Do you want to load or continue?", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE, 0, null, buttons, buttons[2]);
    if (rc == 0) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= colCountState; i++) {
            // to do something
        }
    if (rc == 1) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= colCountState; i++) {
            // to do something
        }

    }
```

Comment: If validation fails, it shows error message and reopens this four-field JOptionPane. So far so goood, but, problem is - second time it don't validate fields anymore.

Comment: Idea is to prevent user from adding empty or half-empty rows to my table. If validation fails (one of four fields are empty) error message must be shown and after accepting this message this first JOptionPane must reopen for user to complete all fields.